# How to specify AES-256 algorithm when creating GPG key?

Tags: encryption, gpg, password-store

Pardon me if this is not possible. My goal is to utilise [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/). From the conducted research, it appears that the `pass` command utility will require a GPG key before you can store your sensitive data.

Now, in order to generate a GPG key, one would run the following command

```
gpg --full-generate-key
```

which is a pre-requisite to using `pass`.

From the output, we can see that the options to choose from are as follows:

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27; Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

gpg: directory '/home/user1/.gnupg' created
gpg: keybox '/home/user1/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
Please select what kind of key you want:
   (1) RSA and RSA (default)
   (2) DSA and Elgamal
   (3) DSA (sign only)
   (4) RSA (sign only)
  (14) Existing key from card
Your selection?
```

As you can see, you can use RSA or DSA, despite GPG specifying that you can use `AES256`.

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27
libgcrypt 1.8.8
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GNU GPL-3.0-or-later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /home/user1/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

Does that mean it is impossible to secure your passwords in `pass` using `AES256` encryption method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is unfortunately not possible.

- [AES256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) is a [*symmetric-key* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm), i.e. the same key is used for encrypting and decrypting.
- The `--generate-key` or `--full-generate-key` option of `gpg` is used to create an [*asymmetric public/private key pair*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography), where the public key is used for encryption and the private key for decryption.

Note that `AES256` is listed under the options for "Cipher", not "Pubkey".

**That said**, I can understand that you would prefer the higher security level of AES256 over RSA. It seems however that the [ECDSA and ED25519 algorithms can provide similar security](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67314) to AES256.

To enable it in `gpg2`, you will need to [specify the `--expert` option](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/245405/281475). When asked "what kind of key you want", choose

```
(9) ECC and ECC
```

with either `NIST P-256` or `Curve 25519`, respectively. [Both curve algorithms provide the same level of security](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/50890/281475), with ED25519 being a tiny bit faster than ECDSA.

Comment: AES256 may still relevant in public key crypto, albeït indirectly; a public key / private key may be used to encrypt / decrypt a hidden symmetric key (e.g. AES256) since asymmetric key operations are computationally slow while symmetric key operations are comparably faster.